# Ember Firebase authentication session doesn't seem inject

Tags: ember.js

In services\session.js:

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Service.extend({
      currentUser: null,
      login(user){
        this.set('currentUser', user);
        console.log("currentUser in service session js"+currentUser);
      },
    });
```

In index.js:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    firebaseApp: Ember.inject.service(),
    session: Ember.inject.service(),


        beforeModel() {
        const auth = this.get('firebaseApp').auth();
        const user1 = auth.currentUser;

        if ((user1 !== null)&&(user1 !== undefined)&&(user1 !== ""))
        {
            const em=user1.email;
            const sessionUser=this.get("session").login(user1);

            console.log("this is email in index route beforeModel "+em);
            console.log("this is sessionUser email in index route beforeModel "+sessionUser);
```

I use firebase auth, which works fine. However, when I try to inject current user in session I created in service, both `sessionUser` and `currentUser` get undefined error messages. I do have  `user1.email` recognized correctly since that's how user model is defined. Any inputs?

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but if ever you can't make Firebase work you could try Ember Simple Auth (which is not simple either)

Comment: thanks but firebase works, just session not working yet. must be my own mistake somewhere.

Comment: Unrelated, but you can optimise to `if ((user1 !== null)&&(user1 !== undefined)&&(user1 !== ""))` to `if (!Ember.isBlank(user1))`. Documentation on http://emberjs.com/api/#method_isBlank

Comment: !Ember.isBlank() is cool! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps start by updating:

```
console.log("currentUser in service session js"+currentUser);
```

to

```
console.log(`currentUser in service session js ${user}`);
```

Comment: thanks Jan, above solution works. So now i have an object "user" injected from index.js to session.js .  I am not sure why this.set('currentUser', user) doesn't give currentUser value since i can't use console.log to display it.  But more important, how to get this session property of user ( or currentUser) from route . I am trying this.get('session.user') or  const sessionUser=this.get('session.user')  or use 'currentUser' to replace 'user' but none works when i test using console.log .

Comment: To update and close, this.get('session.currentUser').email works.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to try first login and only after set the currentUser:

```
const sessionUser=this.get("session").login(user1);
```

to something like:

```
this.get("session").login(user1);
const.sessionUser = this.get("sessions.currentUser");
```